# Is that possible to have an IF statement inside a SET?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in Oracle with a column named `ERROR_CODE` (which is a `VARCHAR2`) initially set to `NULL` for every value. I would like to update it with an `UPDATE` statement like in the following statement:

```
UPDATE SNAPSHOT_TEST
SET ERROR_CODE = 
  IF(...) THEN NVL2(ERROR_CODE, CONCAT(ERROR_CODE, ',8'), '9')
    ELIF(...) THEN NVL2(ERROR_CODE, CONCAT(ERROR_CODE, ',9'), '9') 
    ELIF(...) ...
  END IF;
```

I tried to use a `CASE` statement to achieve this result and it works but it's not what I need, because multiple conditions can match at the same time and if that happens I need to concatenate the error code as in the statement I inserted before, having '8,9' in the end, for example.
is there a way to achieve this in Oracle?

Comment: You can add n condition in CASE statement, also you can do nested case. Post your sample condition

Comment: Show some sample data and expected output (tabular form) in text format. Don't expect us to reverse engineer from the query to guess what your intended output is.

Comment: As I said in another comment, I cannot post my conditions because they are very big. To simplify, you can think at them as something like ID > 10, ID > 20, ID > 30 and so on, something which can be matched multiple times. However the conditions are irrelevant from the question. What's important is that in the end, all the error codes matched for each condition would be displayed in the `ERROR_CODE` column separated by a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE SNAPSHOT_TEST
SET ERROR_CODE = 
    CASE  WHEN ... THEN NVL2(ERROR_CODE, CONCAT(ERROR_CODE, ',8'), '9')
          WHEN ... THEN NVL2(ERROR_CODE, CONCAT(ERROR_CODE, ',9'), '9') 
          ELSE ...
    END;
```

---

> having '8,9' in the end

```
UPDATE SNAPSHOT_TEST
SET ERROR_CODE =
  ERROR_CODE || CASE WHEN ... THEN '8' END || CASE WHEN ... THEN '9' END
```

Comment: As I have already said in my question, I tried to use a `CASE` statement and it works but, with that way, only **one**  `THEN` clause will be executed and it's not what I need.

Comment: @Rexam First of all you cannot update the same column twice at one run. Second please post your **real** scenario with sample data and https://dbfiddle.uk

Answer (score 1):

As the other answerers said, we would need some minimal sample data and sample conditions to recommend a solution.

For instance, reading "... multiple conditions ... having 8,9 in the end ..." makes me think of `LISTAGG`, but I cannot formulate this as an answer because I have not the slightest clue about the conditions.

Comment: Each condition is very big and it involves some `NOT IN` and `IN` clauses and other tables of my DB: that's why I didn't insert them. However they are irrelevant for my question. To simplify, you can think at them as something like `ID > 10`, `ID > 20`, `ID > 30` and so on, something which can be matched multiple times.

Comment: OK, thanks. But this is still too vague for me to find a solution. I appreciate that it is actually very hard to simplify the data for a question so that other people can easily understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

> multiple conditions can match at the same time and if that happens I need to concatenate the error code

So, concatenate the error codes, with a case expression deciding if each is needed:

```
update snapshot_test
set error_code = 
  ltrim(
    case when (...) then ',8' end
    || case when (...) then ',9' end
    || case when (...) then ',10' end
    ...
    , ',');
```

As they all add a comma, the `ltrim` removes the extra one created by the first match.

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f0fbf815e36255af8f5ff7c7013b337f) with completely arbitrary and artificial conditions, since we have nothing real to work with.

(Rather belatedly, I realise this is pretty much what @LukaszSzozda's edit is doing; except this includes the commas.)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution on my own: even if Lukasz's question, after his edit, may actually work, it is more performing in this case to have separate `UPDATE` in cascade as in the following snippet:

```
UPDATE SNAPSHOT_TEST
SET ERROR_CODE = NVL2(ERROR_CODE, CONCAT(ERROR_CODE, ',8'), '8')
WHERE (...);

UPDATE SNAPSHOT_TEST
SET ERROR_CODE = NVL2(ERROR_CODE, CONCAT(ERROR_CODE, ',9'), '9')
WHERE (...);
```

In this way, if the `ERROR_CODE` is `NULL` it will be set for the first time with the first value matched, otherwise another error code will be added with a comma.

Comment: Multiple UPDATEs work of course, but this is unnecessary work, slowing things down, and preventing it from scaling if your database grows. I'm sure it can and should be done in one go.

Comment: @wolφi why do you say "preventing it from scaling"? If another condition would be added in the future, I will simply add an `UPDATE` statement to my script.

Comment: In a large database, `UPDATE`s are very costly, because the before and after images need to be saved, indexes need to be updated, and this is often done more than once per table block. This being error codes, I hope your table will not grow very much, but this being stackoverflow, I try to find solutions that work not only with small but also with large tables.